# Creating Mandatory field based on Dropdown. [HTML, JAVASCRIPT, JQuery]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, aem

I have a dropdown [name="./fixedListForm"] where we have 2 fields

1. External
2. Static Content

[Dropdown values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMXgr.png)
On Selection of External, will enable a multifield with 2 fields.

1. TabID [Text Field]
2. Alt Text [Text Field]

Since the above two fields are multifield we can add n number of fields with names. e.g.

1. Tab ID [Text Field, stored with name=./fixedList/item0/./tabId]
2. Alt Text [text Field, , stored with name=./fixedList/item0/./alt]
   **Add**
3. Tab ID [Text Field, stored with name=./fixedList/item1/./tabId]
4. Alt Text [text Field, , stored with name=./fixedList/item1/./alt]
   **Add**

[Tab ID in External multifield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLBt4.png)

And so on… it will increase item0, item1, item2…
And each items holds [./tabid and ./alt]

On Selection of Static Content, another set of multifield with 2 fields will be added

1. Tab ID [Text Field]
2. Alt Text [text Field]

Since the above two fields are multifield we can add n number of fields with name. e.g.

1. Tab ID [Text Field, stored with name ./staticContent/item0/./tabId]
2. Alt Text [text Field, , stored with name ./staticContent/item0/./alt]
   **Add**
3. Tab ID [Text Field, stored with name  ./staticContent/item1/./tabId]
4. Alt Text [text Field, , stored with name ./staticContent/item1/./alt]
   **Add**

And so on… it will increase item0, item1, item2… And each items holds [./tabid and ./alt]
[Tab Id in Static Multifield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zC5i.png)

Now the requirement here is I have to make alt text mandatory if we have some value in TAB ID.
Means something like

```
 var tabId = $('.cmp-list__editor').find('input[name *="./tabId"]').val();
    if (tabId == "") {
        $('.cmp-teaser__editor').find('input[name *="./alt"]').attr("aria-required", false);
    }else{$('.cmp-list__editor').find('input[name *="./alt"]').attr("aria-required", true);}
```

where .cmp-list__editor is class of parent Div.
The problem here I am facing is the above code works fine if we have a single value field i.e. only Single TABID and ALT text.

But here we have to create a loop where

1. It will search from the dropdown value
2. if dropdown have selected value as external, logic will apply for making alt text mandatory if we have some value in TAB ID
   [./fixedList/item0/./tabId - ./fixedList/item0/./alt]
   [./fixedList/item1/./tabId - ./fixedList/item1/./alt]
3. if dropdown have selected value as static, logic will apply for making alt text mandatory if we have some value in TAB ID
   [./staticContent/item0/./tabId - ./staticContent/item0/./alt]
   [./staticContent/item1/./tabId - ./staticContent/item1/./alt]

Comment: Your Q is to long and complex (Add only the specific idea you want to get). Sound more like a freelancer task. Also add code examples (Not screenshots). Google "add code to stackoverflow"

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the HTML for the multifield , each of your multifield is inside `coral-multifield-item`. May be you can get this element ( which will return all added to the dialog at that point of time) . Once you get this , iterate over each element.

```
var items = $("coral-multifield-item")
```

[coral-multifield-item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpF4A.png)

For your individual field add a unique class like below

[granite:class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF6TU.png)

Once that is added , you can do the below to get the value of those fields

```
$( items ).each(function( index ) {
 console.log($( this ).find(".test-class").val());
});
```

Assuming test-class is the class added to the first textfields in my multifield, the above JS will print the value of my first text fields in the JS . Do similar logic to all the fields and get it easily in the jquery.

You can tweak this logic and try to achieve your requirement if you are familiar with Jquery. Else take help from someone who is good with Jquery.